# how can we get details from another database inside a plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, database-connectivity

I created a plugin in wordpress to display earnings by using a shortcode.The details to display while using shortcode are stored in another database.I used direct database connection in plugin to fetch details from the that database.I used the following code

```
function earnings_shortcode($atts, $content, $tag)
     {  //echo $atts[0];echo '<br>';
         $str=base64_encode(1);
         base64_decode($str);
         $length = 4;
         $res = trim(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $atts[0]));
$mydb1 = new wpdb('root','','db_test','localhost');
$rows = $mydb1->get_row("SELECT total,paydate FROM `tbl_shotcode` WHERE userid = $res", ARRAY_A);
echo "Payout on -" .$rows['paydate']; echo '<br/>';
echo "Total for next Pay Period:-" .$rows['total'];
}
```

Is there any better option to access another database inside a plugin with out hard coding the username and password.please suggest a solution.

Comment: Is this an external database? Or will the database exist on the same server as WP?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to access the database and be authenticated to do queries. You can't get into a properly configured database without login in.

You can, however, make your $mydb1 variable global and define it at the top of your file (or in your constructor class) to be accessed by all your functions. I recommend putting it in a class to manage it more easily.